# cache manifest with asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, asset-pipeline, cache-manifest

What would be the best way to have a html5 cache manifest with the rails asset pipeline? I'm thinking of adding an erb file to app/assets that has the paths of all the assets contained in it. This would work but has a couple problems right off the bat:

- How could I increment the version number?
- How can I make sure the http content type is set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we're doing it on an app right now:

- To handle the generation of the cache manifest file, we are using [Rack::Offline](https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline)
- We then configure this to point to, for instance, `"/assets/application.css"`
- In the layouts/views, we are NOT using the `stylesheet_link_tag`, `javascript_include_tag` or `image_tag helpers` for cache-able assets so that we don't get a link to the assets with the hash in it, eg `"/assets/application-2345234...2344.css"`

This works because when the assets are precompiled, `rake assets:precompile:nondigest` creates versions of the files without the hash in the name, and then `Rack::Offline` checks these to generate a new manifest (or not).

Comment: I've also used this approach and it works for now. But this is certainly not a solution I'd like to keep over longer period time. It's more a hack than a proper way to do it :) I've been looking for a solution to get rack-offline and assets pipeline work nice together but have not yet found a way. Anyone else got rack-offline and rails' 3.1 assets pipeline working nice together?

Comment: Couldn't you get around the third point by setting `config.assets.digest = false` in `production.rb`?

Answer (score -4):

Sprockets provides you with one by default.

in one of your environment configs (/config/environments/development.rb)

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = false
```

and in your html file:

```
<html manifest="manifest.yml">
```

running

```
rake:precompile
```

will give you a manifest file to public/assets/manifest.yml

Comment: This actually isn't in the HTML5 offline cache manifest format - it won't work.

Comment: Voted down b/c this is a yml file not an appcache manifest...  Out of curiosity though, what browsers support this (if any)?

Comment: A better answer would have been to use this YAML file but not sure it will be complete (missing image for example).